# How to make service threadsafe (restful)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Using Spring Boot, I have a service class, that has a private field. The field is read and modified by different methods.

```
@Service
...
   private int maxPoints
```

A rest controller uses that service. I am afraid that different, parallel rest consumers will lead to different threads and that the private variable is not threadsafe.

Whats the best way, to assure thread safety with spring boot and rest?

Answer (score 0):

Your service is instantiated as a singleton by default which means that you will have only one instance of that service through your application lifetime.

In order to make "maxPoints" thread-safe you need to make sure that the methods where you are using "maxPoints" are thread-safe. The easiest way to do that is with "synchronized".
A synchronized block in Java can only be executed a single thread at a time.

```
public synchronized void changeMaxPoints() {
    ...
    // change maxPoints
    ...
}
```

The second way to achieve this is by using [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).